# Prerequisites for Power Integrity Analysis

Tags: simulation, signal-integrity, power-integrity

I try to learn about the topic of Power Integrity Analysis of an PCB, i.e. analysing the Power Distribution network (PDN) of a PCB to locate the regions of biggest noise or DC voltage droop.

Independent of the concrete CAD package used, where and how can I learn about the device models used for such an analysis. There are e.g. IBIS models for many ICs that provide the information for signal integrity simulations - what would be the analogy for PI Analysis? Do manufacturers usually provide models for PI or do engineers create there own ones based on assumptions on current peak amplitudes and frequencies? I doubt that because I suppose that would be plain guessing most of the times since the device-internal behaviour is only known by the manufacturer.

Comment: Usually conduction losses are simplified by online track resistance calculators for heavy currents.  EMC design comes with experience of knowing how high Ldi/dt in inductive loops should be minimized as well high current spikes with step voltage on load capacitance.  Generally high speed clocks >10MHz use ground guard tracks to minimize unintended RF radiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to get is the s-parameter measurements of the capacitors. Some manufacturers are better than others. Murata, for example, have a really detailed online tool. It's a good idea to think about this before choosing components.

The current draw is a big problem. Manufacturers very rarely, read almost never, provide the shape of the drawn current pulses. This is because it all depends on the application. However, you can have some assumptions. The worst case scenario is a Dirac pulse, which has a flat frequency domain representation. You can relax that to say a 10th of the clock period.

After you have that there are generally two steps to PI analysis. You simulate the impedance of the power network at each IC. This will show you whether you need to place more decoupling capacitors to lower the impedance at specific frequencies. You can also check the resonant frequencies of the planes. After that, you need to put your current draw model on the ICs, and do a frequency sweep. Now, you will be able to see what the noise is etc.

In the majority of cases I have worked on, the impedance analysis, which requires only the capacitor data, is all you need. You can do the more detailed analysis, if you want to minimize the capacitance or are worried about current loops crossing each other. Generally, you can assume that current is drawn in Dirac pulses, and design the impedance budget for that. It works surprisingly well even for Gbps applications.

Comment: How can I know, what value the target impedance at the IC pins should have? Assuming dirac pulses (or pulses of a 10th of the clock frequency) seems reasonable but how can I estimate the "magnitude" of the drawn current pulses? Essentially, this is guessing without manufacturer information, right?

Comment: @Junius You get the magnitude from the power consumption. The power consumption will give you the amount of charge needed each clock cycle. The pulse area must then equal the charge. You can then calculate the target impedance by using the amount of voltage drop you can tolerate. With the Dirac pulse method all your harmonics are equal, but you have to set a maximum frequency. You can set something like 10/100 times the operating frequency. Above that, you assume there are no harmonics.

Comment: Ok, so assume a processor with a clock speed of 200MHz that has a max. power rating of 500mA on the 1.5V rail. That means there are Q = 2.5nC delivered each clock cycle. Assume current is drawn for only 1% of the clock cycle time that would mean that the current peaks during this time are I = Q*200E6*100 = 50A (if all of the energy is delivered in this single harmonic of 100*fclock). And since I*t=C*U, I can calculate the value for C to allow a specific voltage drop at this harmonic. So for 100mV drop, I would need a C=(0.5/(200E6*100))/0.1 = 250nF capacitance, right?

Comment: P.S.: Of course the assumption that all of the energy is delivered in this short amount of time seems unrealistic, but the method could be used to include assumptions on other (lower frequency) "harmonics" also to have some "floor" of low impedance versus frequency...

Comment: @Junius All the current is not delivered in a single harmonic. You take the Fourier transform of the pulse. After that you can work out voltage drop contributions from each frequency. If you have a flat impedance response, you will get a pulsed voltage drop. Keep in mind you are adding sin/cos waves. Capacitors at those frequencies are not really capacitive. We generally use optimization programs in order to figure out the right capacitor combination, which is quite hard by hand as they tend to resonate.

Comment: Right, I mentioned that in my "P.S-comment" above, which came a bit late.. ;-) Thanks